# What static means in swift

Tags: swift, properties, static

I am following the stanford iOS / swift [tutorial](https://itunes.apple.com/de/course/developing-ios-9-apps-swift/id1104579961). In the 4th video he is using this code

```
private struct Ratios {
    static let SkullRadiusToEyeOffset : CGFloat = 3
    static let SkullRadiusToEyeRadius : CGFloat = 10
    static let SkullRadiusToMouthWidth : CGFloat = 1
    static let SkullRadiusToMouthHeight : CGFloat = 3
    static let SkullRadiusToMouthOffset: CGFloat = 3
    static let SkullRadiusToBrowOffset : CGFloat = 5
    }
```

I don't really understand what static and type property means and why it don't works if I don't use static. Can someone explain me please ?

Comment: Have you Googled `What static means in swift` (or `swift static properties` for better results)? Remember, that should always be your starting point *above* asking a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static values can be accessed without creating a class instance and are only created once per class, no matter how many instances you create.